# Como atribuir valores aos itens do menu dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-3, dropdown

[segue print da tela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg1hL.jpg)

nao sei muito bem explicar mas gostaria que os itens do meu menu funcionassem e abrisse por exemplo outra página quando clicasse em menu, ou nos itens que estivessem no menu

segue o código:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Controle de Entrega de Produtos</a>
        </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Categorias</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Usuários</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</body>
```

```
   

<?php
require 'config.php';

$lista = [];
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuario" );
if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
    $lista = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Categorias</th>
        <th>Clientes</th>
        <th>Entregas</th>
        <th>Estados</th>
        <th>Fornecedores</th>
        <th>Produtos</th>
        <th>Usuários</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($lista as $usuario): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$usuario['id'];?></td>
            <td><?=$usuario['nome'];?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?=$usuario['email'];?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="editar.php?id=<?= $usuario['id'];?>">[ Editar ]</a>
                <a href="excluir.php?id=<?=$usuario['id'];?>">[ Excluir ] </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>     

</table>

<a href="cadastrar.php">Cadastrar Usuários</a>
```

Comment: já tentou dentro do seu `dropdown-menu`  em `<li><a href="#">Categorias</a></li>` trocar o `#` por pelos links que você deseja?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: tentei dar uma melhorada, se alguem puder me ajudar por favor!!!